# How to check procedure is run and user is exist?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have procedure like this?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `check_user`(in username varchar(100), in pass varchar(5000))
BEGIN
select * from users where email=username and password = pass;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

So i call procedure like this.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "get_user";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", un);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", Security.Encrypt(pass));
int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

it shows result as 0. Because not any row affected. In this case can't identify user is exist or not. User exist or not result always 0. **So how can i get user is exist or not** ?

Comment: Replace ExecuteNonQuery by ExecuteScalar

Comment: Do you need `SELECT *` if you are just going to check if user exists (as your procedure name suggests)? In that case, it would be better to use `SELECT id` or `SELECT user_id` (depending on your table). Also, I would suggest creating a function, because you expect result from it. See more at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html

Comment: so what will that return ? and how to check ? @SteveB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery  should not be used in SELECT statements.

ExecuteNonQuery method is to be used to perform 'Data Manipulation Language'. This is used only in INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE.

ExecuteScalar method will return a single value in the first row, first column from a SELECT statement. So changing your query with SELECT COUNT(*).. can be use.

The ExecuteReader Method will return the result set of a SELECT. This method is to be used when you're querying for a bunch of results, such as rows from a table etc.

Change your query with this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email=username AND password = pass;
```

And use ExecuteScalar() and you are ready to go.

Or you can use DataAdapter Fill like this:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "get_user";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", un);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", Security.Encrypt(pass));

DataTable data = new DataTable();
using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    da.Fill(data);
}

if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
    result = Convert.ToInt32(data.Rows[0][0].ToString());
```

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx).